# Where do I place citations

Tags: citations, writing, formatting

I'm writing a math paper using TexShop that is almost entirely original but I got help with a trig proof; I found a formula in a book that I improved upon, and then got help finding a number series that completed my improvement. I would like to cite the help I got and at least one book but I don't know the proper place to put citations, inline or at the end of the paper. Do I do

1) statement....

citation

more statements

or

2)Topic

statements....statements

topic

statements

last statement of paper

all citations

Comment: The formatting of such things depends where you want to publish it. Check out examples in that journal to see how other authors have done it and the journal has accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found a formula in a book that I improved upon

When you introduce the formula, cite the book, e.g., *the following formula is proposed by Author X [1]*:

> and then got help finding a number series

Presumably you *got help* from someone. You can acknowledge that help at the end of your main body in an *acknowledgements* section. (Use `\section*{Acknowledgements}`.)

Comment: The help I got here and there was from https://math.stackexchange.com in the form of answers to questions I posted. Supposedly the format is in an answer I received [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/135897/how-do-i-cite-sources-in-a-math-paper)

Comment: @poetasis You can cite or acknowledge stackexchange, see https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84965/how-to-cite-an-answer-in-stackexchange and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/citing-stackexchange-postings, for instance. Whether a citation or acknowledge is more appropriate depends on your precise scenario.

Answer (score 4):

While the details are dependent on the venue where you are publishing, most mathematical papers will put the full citations at the end but reference them in the midst of the text (e.g., via a citation number).

You can format these automatically if you use LaTeX, and the [AMS provides widely used packages for formatting](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex).

Answer (score 0):

## Consult the style guide of the journal in question.

Different style guides have different requirements on how different types of citations are to be performed. Harvard is different to IEEE which is in turn different to APA.